# Remote App using CSOM against SP2013 with Claims

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, claims

We have a few applications that currently use managed code CSOM against SP2010 - think of SharePoint as simply a large file store.  The UI is not used at all and all the functionality for the remote app is in the remote app - SP is only a file store.  All of this was developed with CSOM and authentication was handled via Kerberos delegation (browser->Remove App IIS->SP2010) under the end users credentials.  In reality, the app reads files from about 50 sites - and that changes constantly as the data grows so we don't have too many items in a list or too large of a database.

We want to do the exact same thing but move the file store to SP2013 (on-prem) but SP2013 is only setup to use claims - not kerberos.  Is there a way to get the CSOM code authenticated properly - everything we try throws 401's right now?  Does this require a provider hosted app setup?

Anything to get me pointed in the right direction will be helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use apps in an on-prem SP2013 farm, you need to connect the farm to Azure ACS or run server-to-server.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3651-8%20Setting%20up%20your%20on-premises%20environment%20for%20app%20development

Comment: let me change this a bit - I don't want to use apps at all.  I just want to retrieve some data from SharePoint (that uses Claims) and I don't want to tell SharePoint anything about it as far as Apps go.  Since this works via only a Single hop, can't I setup some type of server 2 server trust so it still works?

Comment: If your web app is configured to use Integrated Windows Auth, then you can set the Credentials property on the ClientContext. If you are using a Trusted Identity Provider (federated), then your code will need to perform the auth. This SP2010 code should still apply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx